# Как изменить цвет текста верхней панели?

Tags: android, текст, color

При открытии приложения у меня в верхней панели цвет текса белый но если свернутся то он меняется на тёмный. Можно как-то сделать чтобы при открытии приложения текст в верхней панели был сразу темным?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Ссылка1](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) [Ссылка2](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theme.php)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Если ваш API 23+ вы можете указать этим параметры в AppTheme styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> 
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Если

```
android:windowLightStatusBar
```

установлен `true`, текст `statusBar` будет виден на белом фоне и наоборот, при значении `false` текст будет виден при темном фоне `statusBar`

Например:

```
<!-- Base application theme. --> 
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> 


    <!-- Customize your theme here. --> 
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item> 
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> 
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item> 

    <!-- Status bar stuff. --> 
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> 
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item> 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Изменить цвет текста судя по всему не получится как сказано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27888207/9363441), но можно изменить цвет фона этой полоски и он будет сочетаться с цветом текста. Сделать это можно например программно:

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();

// clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

// add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

// finally change the color
window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.my_statusbar_color));
```

[документация](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)) и [туториал](http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/). Второй вариант - через стиль приложения (так как сказано в комментариях), для этого нужно добавить в стиль приложения цвет:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/statusBarColor</item>
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android) есть подобный вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Что бы изменить на темный, в теме приложения, файл styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
    <!-- android:windowLightStatusBar //реверсирует цвета статусбара
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>-->
```